# Show options with checkboxes in a dropdown list - HTML/JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with this and can't pass through.
I need to show the options on the dropdown list and i'm not succeeding.
It only appears the dropdown and when I click it does not show the options. If anybody could please help it would be much appreciated. Thank You!

Here is my HTML code and CSS:

```css
.dropdown {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* use correct mouse pointer when hovering over the dropdown */
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
/* Display CSS arrow to the right of the dropdown text */

.dropdown:after {
  content: '';
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #000;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
/* Reverse the CSS arrow when the dropdown is active */

.dropdown.is-active:after {
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  margin-top: -9px;
}
.dropdown-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  /* align the dropdown right below the dropdown text */
  border: inherit;
  border-top: none;
  left: -1px;
  /* align the dropdown to the left */
  right: -1px;
  /* align the dropdown to the right */
  opacity: 0;
  /* hide the dropdown */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* avoid mouse click events inside the dropdown */
}
.is-active .dropdown-list {
  opacity: 1;
  /* display the dropdown */
  pointer-events: auto;
  /* make sure that the user still can select checkboxes */
}
.dropdown-list li label {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}
.dropdown-list li label:hover {
  background-color: #c41230;
  color: white;
}



EDIT: Full html code
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cascade.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="pesquisas.js"></script>
            <title>Pesquisa de Imóveis</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div id="tab1" class="dropdown" tabindex="1">
                                            <!--"dropdown-check-list"-->
                                            <span>Anúncio</span>
                                            <!--"anchor"-->
                                            <ul class="dropdown-list">
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type=checkbox name=faceta1 value=valor1>Aluguer</input>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type=checkbox name=faceta1 value=valor2>Venda</input>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type=checkbox name=faceta1 value=valor3>Compra</input>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type=checkbox name=faceta1 value=valor4>Permuta</input>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="dropdown">
                                            <span>Imóveis</span>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-list">
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor1>Apartamento</input>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor2>Moradia</input>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor3>Armazém</input>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor4>T4</input>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor5>Terreno</input>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type=checkbox name=faceta2 value=valor6>Loja</input>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: There's no such thing as `</input>`. Inputs are not containers.

Comment: Where is your jQuery code to add the `is-active` class?

Comment: everything I have tried has failed abysmally.... I am new to jQuery

Comment: Obviously it failed because you're posting here. But you have to post what you tried so we can show you what you did wrong and how to fix it. You don't expect us to just write it for you, do you? Who's getting paid for this, you or us?

Comment: I'm new to jQuery, im not being paid, i'm just trying to learn something

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Javascript code :

```
$(".dropdown").on("click",function()
{
    $(this).addClass("is-active");
});
```

Comment: already added the library and still doesn't work, It needs something more?

Comment: I tried the demo and after I added the code to my javascript code in my netbeans project but it doesn't worked